# Using Java Generics in Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics

When integrating a java library with Scala codebase, running into following error when uisng one of Generic objects from Java into Scala.

```
val MyObject<SomeOtherclass>  = MyObject.factoryMethod()
```

Above code gives a compilation error because it is not a valid scala statement.

How can we use Java generic objects in scala codebase.

Comment: should be something like `val obj = MyObject.factoryMethod`. Scala can usually infer the type.

Comment: Just use Scala syntax MyObject[SomeOtherClass]. You can use generic java classes in Scala just as if they where defined in Scala as the Scala typesystem can express everything that of Java can.

Answer (score 1):

```
val myObject: MyObject[T] = MyObject.factoryMethod ()
```

would be Scala-Syntax. Note that objects are usually written in lower case. The type inference might solve the issue without giving the type explicitly, but it might be a good idea for documentation reasons to specify it though, and to get an early error, if your reasoning was wrong.